# How do you send skype messages from google sheets?

Tags: javascript, skype

I tried a code to send skype messages from google sheets but I got an error `Windows is not defined`. The code for that was as show below and can you help me fix this or can you give me a new code. I wrote this in google sheets script editor(located in tools).

```
function test() {
  var url = "https://swx.cdn.skype.com/shared/v/1.2.35/SkypeBootstrap.min.js";
  var javascript = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  eval(javascript);

  var config = {
    apiKey: 'a42fcebd-5b43-4b89-a065-74450fb91255', // SDK
    apiKeyCC: '9c967f6b-a846-4df2-b43d-5167e47d81e1' // SDK+UI
  }; 

  Skype.initialize({ apiKey: config.apiKey }, function (api) {
    var Application = api.application;
  });
}
```